# For Application Pool Identity, how do you return the logged in user when authentication is both set to anonymous and windows authentication?

Tags: iis, deployment, applicationpoolidentity

I'm new to IIS Deployment.  It looks like the application pool identity user will always show as computer name of the user. So if we use domain/username as app pool identity, it will always treat domain/username regardless who is logged in on the app.

How do you return the computer  name of the  user when authentication is both set to anonymous and windows authentication?

Here's what I have on Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions option = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(option);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

Comment: You might get some basic knowledge from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0 Edit your question to state clearly what is the "logged in user" you are talking about, as the ambiguity around it can prevent this question from being answered.

Comment: Computer name of the user

Comment: Any help? Please

Comment: “Computer name of the user”? What's that? Computer name or user name? If you find it hard to describe, use screen shots.

Comment: it's the network login of the user who log in the computer.

Comment: You won't get that when you enable anonymous authentication (Windows authentication is ignored when anonymous is enabled). And that's exactly what anonymous is.

Comment: It's disabled but i'm getting the error error: "invalid_grant"

Answer (score 0):

> How do you return the computer name of the user when authentication is both set to anonymous and windows authentication?

As far as I know，if you have already enabled the  anonymous authentication, that means all the user will not use windows auth, it will use your IIS anonymous user as the user account.

The user account could be the specific user or the identity pool user based on your setting.

[image]

If you diable the  anonymous authentication, it will use the client user's domain username which could set by client uswer to access your web application.

Comment: Thanks.  However, currently I'm getting the error error: "invalid_grant" (401 (Unauthorized))

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: As far as I know, this issue is normally thrown by the application which has enabled the oauth. Could you please tell me that you have enabled oauth in your web application? Besides, I suggest you could post your web.config setting which related with the windows auth.

Comment: I added my Startup.cs on my main question.

Comment: According to your codes, I found you have enbled the oauth in your application, the error measn that your login user doesn't have the permission to access your web application.

Comment: are you referring this? AllowInsecureHttp = true